# Convert milliseconds to seconds in C

Tags: c, time

Simple C question, how can I correctly and succintly convert milliseconds to seconds.
There are two constraints:

- I've no floating point support in this tiny subset-of-C compiler
- I need the seconds rounded to the nearest second(1-499ms rounds down,500-999ms rounds up. Don't need to care about negative values)

  ```
  int mseconds = 1600; // should be converted to 2 seconds
  int msec = 23487;  // should be converted to 23 seconds
  ```

Comment: How would you want 1500 and 2500 to round (hint: Some other languages let you choose the algorithm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should work

```
int sec = ((msec + 500) / 1000);
```

Comment: That is the cleanest way. I usually do that when I have more then 1.6 seconds to think about it ;-)

Comment: This assumes that: you're rounding away from zero (as opposed to nearest even) in the event of a tie, and that you're not round negative numbers...

Comment: In general: to do an integer divide with rounding, add half of the dividend before dividing. Rowland's caveats apply.

Comment: @Rowland: If you expect negative numbers, then its easy to account for that using (msec<0?-1:1)*500 - of course it means more CPU cycles, so only use it if you actually need it. A similar approach can be used to handle "round towards even".

Answer (score 5):

```
int seconds = msec / 1000;
if (msec % 1000 > 500)
    seconds++;
```

Comment: He explicitly said he needed it rounded.

Comment: You people are too fast to downvote :) It took me 20 seconds after I posted to realise that rounding is needed and to add rounding part, and by that time I got 2 downvotes :)

Answer (score 4):

At first I did not want to write this answer after the testing on x86, but the testing on sparc Solaris showed it had a performance gain compared with "obvious solution", so maybe it would be useful to someone. I've taken it from [a PDF](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) that accompanies the book [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/). Here it goes:

```
unsigned msec2sec(unsigned n) {
  unsigned q, r, t;
  n = n + 500;
  t = (n >> 7) + (n >> 8) + (n >> 12);
  q = (n >> 1) + t + (n >> 15) + (t >> 11) + (t >> 14);
  q = q >> 9;
  r = n - q*1000;
  return q + ((r + 24) >> 10);
}
```

as opposed to:

```
unsigned msec2sec_obvious(unsigned n) {
  return (n + 500)/1000;
}
```

On x86 the "obvious algorithm" translates into adding 500 and then a long multiply by 274877907, followed by grabbing the most significant 32 bits from edx and shifting them 6 bit right - so it beats this code above hands down (~5 times times performance difference).

However, on Solaris/sparc, the "obvious" is transformed into a call to .udiv - which all in all turns out to give a performance difference of ~2.5 times in another direction.

Comment: this approach used when division operation was 5-25 CPU cycles long without RISK-V and with really SLOW Intel architecture. Basically, the code above was implemented in hardware, and because hardware implementations was much slower that software implementation without division operation all goes much faster. the reason for this was in the roots of this comes from the fact that math co-processor was implemented as separate arithmetic module physically attached to motherboard separately from main CPU module (and sold separately, that was clear marketing choice of product managers of the past)

Comment: since then, co-processor was removed, division takes only one CPU cycle or less (obviously nowadays once CPU cycle can calculate up to several division operations, got some additional registers for that, get cache level1,2,3 was introduced as well as branch predictions and forward calculations and calculated or even predicted and calculated even before user asks for division operations, then... well this code about having no sense at all, cause it will be predicted since branch prediction now has enough depth it still be a times slower than hardware realization of division operation

Comment: and, as times goes on on modern CPU does not really matters, on which architecture it can be either RISK or Non-RISK architectures, since even RISK goes forward close to some other solutions invented in opposite architectures, and opposite architectures moves forward to RISK ideas quickly so nowadays almost all CPU-s are hybrid, not a clear ancestors, you can see this shifts in Apple M1/M2/M3 and AMD latest CPU buses