# Convert milliseconds to minutes

Tags: objective-c, c, math, time

How I can convert milliseconds to minutes or hours, in Objective-C or C?

Comment: There's 1000 milliseconds in a second.  There's 60 seconds in a minute.  966000 / 1000 => 966 / 60 => 16 minutes.

Comment: Close-as-off-topic lacks as "belongs on math.stackexchange.com" option...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert milliseconds to seconds in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294885/convert-milliseconds-to-seconds-in-c)

Comment: @R: I think this would get closed there as "Off-topic: programming question."

Comment: Are your seconds representing duration, or absolute time? Are you interested in correct handling of leap seconds?

Comment: Not a real question?! It's a perfectly valid question. It's just a dupe.

Comment: I believe Maxime wants to do this programmatically and it therefore is a valid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use simple division. Use floating point numbers so that you don't lose precision from rounding.

```
float milliseconds = 966000.0;
float seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0;
float minutes = seconds / 60.0;
float hours = minutes / 60.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MSEC_PER_SEC    1000L
#define SEC_PER_MIN     60
#define MIN_PER_HOUR    60

int msec = 966000;
int min  = msec / (MSEC_PER_SEC * SEC_PER_MIN);
int hr   = min  / (MIN_PER_HOUR);
```

Comment: +1 for use of named constants

Comment: @progrmr Descriptive, but not more, as you can assume these constants to NEVER change their values in a meaningful context.

Comment: @Christian, magic numbers without a meaningful name are bad style, no matter if their values change in this universe or not.

Answer (score 2):

sounds a bit like a joke but what the heck…

- divide by 60*1000… for minutes.
- divide by 60*60*1000… for hours.

the beauty of it it works in all programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 1000 to get seconds. Divide seconds by 60 to get minutes.